# How to find the API chain starting from one type, and return another type in the end?

Tags: java

For example, given type URL, String is the type in need. Below is a valid chain:

```
new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(URL.openStream()).readLine()
```

OR another one relying on Apache Commons IO library:

```
IOUtils.toString(URL.openStream())
```

In order to find API chain like those, it seems to require an API index that keeps records of all method signatures. Is there existing solution for this kind of searching?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Would `URL.toString()` be valid? How do you get from one to the other? What is the rule? Is this for static code analysis?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes URL.toString() is valid too. The goal is to get all such valid chains. One of the motivations is to save time on API researching when not familiar with APIs of a new domain.

Comment: In that case, the answer is there are infinite such chains. Where do you stop?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I agree there will be if loops are allowed like String.toString(). How about not allowing loops in chains?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for something that's like a "six degrees of separation" for type conversion? This is great idea. I don't know of anyone building such a tool, but it seems like leveraging Maven Central and pumping things into a graph where methods' type inputs / outputs can be traversed would be a start.

I've found myself doing lots of "type pimping" in Scala to do a similar thing, yet still by hand. The use of implicits in Scala allows this to happen transparently in the call-site code. It also allows one to "enrich" an existing type (often those that are final, like String), with new methods.

So, in Java, for a simple type conversions (e.g. String to URL) have you looked at http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-convert/ It comes with a handful of pre-packaged conversions, and the means to add your own much like (albeit clumsier than) the Scala "pimping".

Nonetheless, strictly, you're not converting a URL to a String there. What you are doing is converting the (hopefully text-based) representation of the resource at the given URL to a String. That is a legitimate need but not really something represented in the types as they stand. What you'd want is a TextualResource (which is constructed with a URL) to String converter. Given that new TextualResource type would want to do something useful, it would probably implement your first example in its toString method anyway.

Comment: Your first paragraph reads my mind. I hope to get the most out of all the accumulated Java libraries to date.